# Problem when uploading a new app bundle to play store

Tags: java, android, console, release

I get the well known error in the developer console, but I am not able to fix it.
Here is the error message:
"Resolve these errors before starting the rollout of this release. You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs."
I know, that in all postings related to this it is said, that it has to do with the version code. Of course I know that and I have changed it several times to a higher number. So this cannot be the problem.
I want to publish a new version of may Wear OS-App. It has a wear- and a mobile-module. So I created an app bundle from the mobile module and uploaded this. Then this error is shown.
What is the problem?
Thanks for any help!
Chris

For wear:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 41
        applicationId "de.braeuer_itl.mywatchface"
        versionName "4.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }



}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

For mobile:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 40
        applicationId "de.braeuer_itl.mywatchface"
        versionName "4.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
 ...
}
```

**I found the error.** It was *not* the versionCode. I added somehow the line:
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>`
in the mobile-manifest, which is wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please reproduce a part of your code and include it in your question if possible, to give a better perspective.

Comment: versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"   kindly change these both then try to upload

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answers!
Unfortunately this (changing the versionCode) does not work. I tried this before several times. There must be a bigger problem.
``

Comment: I found the error. It was *not* the versionCode. I added somehow the line:
`<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>`
in the mobile-manifest, which is wrong.